# Allow Nulls on a few fields Newtonsoft - even with NullValueHandling.Ignore at startup

Tags: c#, null, json.net

I have a field that I need to print that is false and another int that needs to be 0.  I don't want to add the ignore atribute on every other property in my application

I have tried this:
[JsonProperty(Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.AllowNull)]

I have tried ShouldSerializePropertyName()

I have tried writing my own ContractResolver ... and adding property.Ignore = false

What else can I do to print these 2 properties?

my startup looks like this:

```
 services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
         });
```

my POCO just looks like this:

```
public class Extension : Element
{

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public Boolean valueBoolean { get; set; }

    public DateTime valueDateTime { get; set; }   

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public int valueInteger { get; set; }

  public bool ShouldSerializevalueBoolean()
    {

 //this never gets called - I have played around with the case of this upper lower camel etc and neither of these are getting called... a few answers have had that issue as well fyi
        return true;
    }
```

I've tried a lot in my resolver... nothing seems to work:

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(Extension) && property.PropertyName == "valueBoolean")
        {
            property.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
           // property.Ignored = false;
            //if (property.Ignored)
            //{
            //    property.Ignored = false;
            //}

            //property.ShouldSerialize =
            //    instance =>
            //   {
            //       Extension e = (Extension)instance;
            //       e.valueString = e.valueString + "made it here valueBoolean";
            //       return true;//e.ShouldSerializeValueBoolean();
            //   };
 }

        return property;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]` on the properties you want to include?

Comment: Just tried it- no luck ~,~ thx tho

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] which reproduces the issue so we can help you fix it?  Right now it is difficult to advise because we can't see what you're doing, so all we can do is guess.

Comment: done - I can't believe this would not have an easy fix, but it appears that if you say ignore nulls, then that's it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this again my issue was that these properties were not nullable.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public Boolean? valueBoolean { get; set; }
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public int? valueInteger { get; set; }
```

Fixed my issue!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you don't want to make those properties nullable, you can use `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]` on the properties instead to override what you have in the settings.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  Unless they are actually "nullable" with the "?" after the type, the compiler never allows them to be null in which case newtonsoft can't either.... from the way I understand it.  Thx tho

Comment: `NullValueHandling` controls whether or not a `null` value will be emitted during serialization.  You're right that value types like `bool` and `int` must be made nullable in order to be set to null so that `NullValueHandling` would have an effect on them.  However, your original question seemed to be that you had a *non*-nullable `bool` and `int` with values `false` and `0` respectively, and you were trying to include those.  In that case, you could use `DefaultValueHandling`, because that setting controls what happens when value types have default values.